# Solidity whitelisting many adresses

Tags: solidity, dapps

I want to whitelist 1000 wallets every month or so. I can add wallets to whitelist with smartcontarct one by one but it takes so much time and gas fee. Is there a faster way?

```
mapping(address => bool) public addresses;

    function whitelistAddresses(address[] _addresses) onlyOwner {
        require(!whitelistInitialized);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
            addresses[_addresses[i]] = true;
        }
```

How can I check the adresses from data/json/database to be sure that they are in the whitelist? When I searched this topic, I saw signatures used for verification but still didnt really understood how can I compare it with my data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a faster way?

You can create a [Patricia tree of all addresses](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity-examples/blob/master/docs/patricia_tree/PatriciaTree.md).

[See post on Uniswap airdrop of 180k+ addresses](https://steveng.medium.com/performing-merkle-airdrop-like-uniswap-85e43543a592?source=rss------cryptocurrency-5)

Comment: Thank you! I will check them out